# Python select tuples with conditions

Tags: python, numpy

```
   module_category    component_category    year_month_sale    year_month_repair 
0              M6                P16          200709            200904   
1              M2                P30          200709            200908   
2              M1                P12          200610            200802   
3              M1                P30          200605            200707   
4              M3                P06          200708            200712
```

I have a dataframe like this. I would like to ask how could I select or create a subset of dataframe with `year_month_repair >= 200802` only such that the result would be like the below?

```
module_category    component_category    year_month_sale    year_month_repair 
0              M6                P16          200709            200904   
1              M2                P30          200709            200908   
2              M1                P12          200610            200802
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try [.loc[]](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc) method:

```
df.loc[df.year_month_repair >= '200802']
```

where `df` is your data frame

Comment: it returned: unorderable types: str() >= int()

Comment: @joycey, i've updated my answer - please check. You didn't specify the types of your columns, so i made an assumption that all your `year_` columns are integers

Answer (score 0):

Pythons filter() would be perfect for this:

```
condition = lambda x: x[3] >= 200802
filteredDataframe = filter(condition, dataframe)
```

I think this codeblock is self-explanatory:

- an anonymous function with [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) is created to be applied to each tuple
- filter applies that function and returns all tuples that return true

Comment: Thanks, I am quite new to python. I would like to ask what does condition = lambda mean?

Comment: I tried to input the code, but it returned error: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: @joycey lambda is a form of creating short, anonymous functions. when you write lambda x: 5 this is the same as def somefunc(x): return 5. in the example, instead of an integer, a bool is returned. Filter then just applies it to every element (dataset) of your datatable and checks for the fourth element of the tuple. If it's bigger than 200802 the lambda returns true and therefore filter knows it should take that tuple.

Comment: I see! Thanks so much!

Comment: Python `filter` would be inredibly slow with large dataframes. Numpy/pandas methods are always preferable.

Comment: @imaluengo I agree, if you have a huge amount of data, filter is not the way to go. However, some dedicated database query system (for example MySQL) would be the way to go. As the PO seems to be new to python, I thought a native python solution would be best, as it also demonstrates how to use it on non-numpy iterables. Also, I'd like to mention that filter is not too terrible, as the loop is outsourced to c code.